# Как заммапить объект в автомаппер?

Tags: c#, automapper

У меня есть сущность

```
public class Option : BaseEntity
{
    public string? Label { get; set; }

    public OptionType Type { get; set; }

    public int Sequence { get; set; }

    public int? MinLimit { get; set; }

    public int? MaxLimit { get; set; }

    public int OptionGroupId { get; set; }

    public int ProductId { get; set; }

    public int CategoryId { get; set; }

    public OptionGroup OptionGroup { get; set; } = null!;

    public Product Product { get; set; } = null!;

    public Category Category { get; set; } = null!;
}
```

Мне нужно в зависимомости от Type

```
public enum OptionType
{
    Range = 1,
    Selector = 2,
    Switch = 3
}
```

Нужно маппить в разные DTO

Я выделил базовую DTO

```
public abstract record BaseOptionDto
{
    public OptionType Type { get; set; }
    
    public int Sequence { get; set; }
    
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }

    public OptionGroupDto OptionGroup { get; set; }
}
```

И вот допустим у меня Type == Range и мне нужно заммапить в

```
public record RangeDto : BaseOptionDto
{
    public int? MinLimit { get; set; }

    public int? MaxLimit { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: создайте свой конвертер, который в зависимости от enum будет вызывать разные `Map<...>`.

Comment: Мой вам совет, откажитесь от маппера, как это делают большинство) Вот что вам мешает сделать к примеру, отдельный класс с методами расширения, а затем просто вызывать где угодно `option.ToDto();`, потратите в разы меньше времени, чем настройка маппинга, потратите меньше ресурсов, получите больше контроля. Советую подумать над этим.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ в вашей практике вы всегда добавляете к классу Dto? А другие варианты используете/видели, например, Response и option.ToResponse()?

Comment: @Lapish Обычно использую просто `ToDto` для всех классов и всех реализаций, так не теряешься. Что касается `Response` (ответ), то тут не совсем подходящий пример, ибо ответ подразумевает то, что мы его получили и нам его надо перевести в нужный класс, а не наоборот, ну а вот `Request` (запрос) ближе, только вот "Запрос" это обычно уже готовый объект, десериализованный, который мы отсылаем, а не простой DTO. Правда тут как посмотреть) Я обычно отделяю DTO от всяких запросов, ну а запросы создаю руками по месту.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ ну Response я подсмотрел и стал использовать как ответ контроллеров/выполнение mediatr или что-то связанное с бд. Например, у нас есть некий сервис и он работает с EF - возвращает коллекцию сущностей из бд. Вы бы назвали эту сущность в коллекции Dto или Response?

Comment: @Lapish Так база это не DTO. DTO это Data Transfer Object, объект для передачи данных (обычно по сети), он не должен иметь логику, он должен содержать только нужные данные). База - это не передача классов, это выполнение запросов, которые за вас генерирует EF, а для простоты там используются простые модели, которые называют также, как называется таблица в базе (пример: класс Person -> таблица Persons), в названии не должно быть каких либо приписок и чего либо еще. Хех, [пример вон нашел](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/web-api/overview/data/using-web-api-with-entity-framework/part-5).

Comment: @Lapish Если речь про то, что вы потом на основе данных из базы формируете объект для ответа на запрос, то да, это DTO, и тут уже сами смотрите, что вам ближе DTO или Response) Я видел и то и то, но чаще, наверно Response, хотя сам использую DTO)

Comment: @EvgeniyZ про коллекцию я имел ввиду естественно получение Person и перегон его маппером в PersonDto или PersonResponse.